# Interrupting threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, interrupt

I've studied Java for almost 8 months now and I'm a little confused abouth interrupting threads.

I have a JavaFX multiThreaded application which displays all the clients connected (ip and port etc.) in a tableview.

When the program starts, I enter port number and press start button, which starts the server class.

I have a serverclass which implements Runnable, and when a client connects, I create an object of client class which extends Thread. Both the server and client class has in its run method:

```
public void run(){
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
```

the server creates a client like this:

```
new Thread(new Client(socket)).start();
```

And what I wonder is if I create a stop button, which invokes a method in the server class that interrupts the server thread, will the client threads automatically be interrupted too?

What I actually want is to be able to change the port without restarting the program. And of course I don't want threads to keep running in the background if I change to another port.

What options do I have in this case? If you miss any information, just leave a comment and I will fix it right away.

Comment: "What I actually want is to be able to change the port without restarting the program. And of course I don't want threads to keep running in the background if I change to another port." So you want to break off any client connection while it is happening? How rude... I think it is much better if you have the worker threads check some variable and let them disconnect cleanly (i.e. using the application protocol).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes haha I want to be able to do that, let's say if I type in wrong port number or anythying.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ok do you mean something like a volatile boolean?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Although I have the feeling that you're a bit stuck on the lower level constructs of the Java language. I would strongly recommend knowing everything about the `java.util.concurrent` package; what you're trying to do may already be in there.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yea lowlevel is fun! Ok I will take a look that. Thanks for the being the only one helping out !

Comment: are you sure you dont want to allow the existing threads to keep running? i would interrupt the single thread which is accepting sockets on the ServerSocket, allow it to recreate the new ServerSocket on the new port. All the existing Threads should be allowed to finish gracefully. (unless there is something about your app I dont know where you need to kill existing connections)

Answer (score 2):

Since the Server and Client are on different Threads, if you interrupt the Server Thread, it will not interrupt the Client Thread. Threads started in other Threads are independent of their parent, so if the parent Thread stops, the child Thread can keep running.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) System.out.println(i);
    }).start;

}).start();

t.interrupt();
```

The child Thread should keep running the program, as it is in a different Thread than the parent. The main job of the parent Thread is to start the child Thread, and if it dies, the child keeps on living.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That was what I thought. I will just recreate the serversocket or maybe if I store all the clientobjects in a linked list, I can just loop through them and close theam, right?

Comment: @Johan That should work, you might want to use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which allows you to do something like `for(Object o : objects) objects.remove(o);` It can be helpful in some cases, but mostly for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! Earlier I've used clientobject = null, but does that stop the thread or only makes the object point to null? Add what you wrote as answer and I will accept :)